# Set cookie and redirect on multiple visits not working as intended

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I have created a script which to me looks like should work but unfortunately there's an issue where it set's cookie2 even the criteria has been met.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if (typeof Cookies.get('cookie1') !== 'undefined') {
            Cookies.set('cookie2', 'true', {expires: 1000});
            window.location.href = "https://google.com/second";
        }
        else
        {
            Cookies.set('cookie1', 'true', {expires: 1000});
            }
            window.location.href = "https://google.com/first";
        }
    });
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if (typeof Cookies.get('cookie2') !== 'undefined') {

            window.location.href = "https://google.com/third";
        }
        else
        {
        }
    });
</script>
```

On user's first visit should go to google.com/first, on user's second visit should go to google.com/second and last visit and every visit after that should go to google.com/third. The second visit isn't being met as look's like cookie 2 has already been inserted even thought it's not in the first "else" function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the problem is with the conditional stating of your if/else condition. It will always go to else condition since the value is set for **cookie1** after the first page load

**window.location.href = "https://google.com/first";**

so you need to add nested if/else condition

Fiddle link :https://jsfiddle.net/kju86Ly9/3/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(getCookie('cookie1'))
    console.log(getCookie('cookie2'))

 if (getCookie('cookie1') !== 'undefined' && getCookie('cookie2') === null) {
        setCookie('cookie2', 'true', 10);
        console.log('https://google.com/first')
  window.location.href = "https://google.com/first";
 } else if (getCookie('cookie2') !== 'undefined' && getCookie('cookie3') === null) {
        setCookie('cookie3', 'true', 10);
        console.log('https://google.com/second')

  window.location.href = "https://google.com/second";
 } else {
        console.log('https://google.com/third')

  window.location.href = "https://google.com/third";
 }


 function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires = "";
  if (days) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
 }

 function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
   var c = ca[i];
   while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
   if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
    }
    function eraseCookie(name) {   
        document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @rishab but it doesn't still work. With your code third isn't loading just second after every visit

Comment: Thanks for following up and improving but now only third is loading everytime (using safari). I feel like it can't handle 2 cookies

Comment: hi @Manny i have made workable code as per your requirement now you can verify by checking this link too https://jsfiddle.net/kju86Ly9/3/

Comment: There seems to be a glitch. After running nothing redirects. I have tried on my site as well doesn't seem to be working

Comment: i have added console logs uncomment the window.location.href